# aws root pinning error CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, libcurl

I am using libcurl and shifting cert pinning to AWS root as per this document https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/

I used the **SHA-256** Hash of Subject Public Key Information data from that website, formed a string:

```
static string PUBLIC_KEY = "sha256//fbe3018031f9586bcbf41727e417b7d1c45c2f47f93be372a17b96b50757d5a2;sha256//7f4296fc5b6a4e3b35d3c369623e364ab1af381d8fa7121533c9d6c633ea2461;sha256//36abc32656acfc645c61b71613c4bf21c787f5cabbee48348d58597803d7abc9;sha256//f7ecded5c66047d28ed6466b543c40e0743abe81d109254dcf845d4c2c7853c5;sha256//2b071c59a0a0ae76b0eadb2bad23bad4580b69c3601b630c2eaf0613afa83f92";
```

and set the string to curl

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY, PUBLIC_KEY.c_str());
```

The curl error I get is `CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH`
Google does not have any insight into why, as far as I searched. If anyone has any input on how to fix this and still pin to the root, it would be super useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. Root pinning is not supported yet. 
13.11 Support intermediate & root pinning for PINNEDPUBLICKEY
CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY does not consider the hashes of intermediate & root certificates when comparing the pinned keys. Therefore it is not compatible with "HTTP Public Key Pinning" as there also intermediate and root certificates can be pinned. This is very useful as it prevents webadmins from "locking themself out of their servers".

Adding this feature would make curls pinning 100% compatible to HPKP and allow more flexible pinning.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html